# sed line number range with an 'inverted' range specified

Tags: regex, linux, sed

When line numbers are specified with sed, it performs the specified operations within the specified range. So,

```
sed -n '5,10 p' < file
```

will print lines 5 through 10 from file. So my understanding is, it scans through the file to find the line number matching the first specified argument (5)and performs the specified operation until the line number matching the second argument (10) is reached. But, when I inverted the range, i.e:

```
sed -n '10,5 p' < file
```

it printed only the 10th line in the file. So, is my assumption regarding the way sed operates incorrect? What causes the 10th line to be even printed, as the specified 'range' is not even an actual valid range?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses):

> An address range can be specified by specifying two addresses separated by a comma (,). An address range matches lines starting from where the first address matches, and continues until the second address matches (inclusively).
>
> If the second address is a regexp, then checking for the ending match will start with the line following the line which matched the first address: a range will always span at least two lines (except of course if the input stream ends).
>
> If the second address is a number less than (or equal to) the line matching the first address, then only the one line is matched.

Note the word "inclusively" in that first paragraph and then the longer explanation in the 3rd paragraph.

Why? Don't go getting metaphysical on us here... :-)

Comment: I guess, that's where I should've started instead of diving into a tutorial... Heard not-so-great things about sed's man page in particular, and so I skipped it. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a range where start and end is a line number, the ending line number must be greater than the starting line number. If the ending line number is lower than or equals the starting line number then the range will apply only to the starting line number. The man page states this, [Peter Bowers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29243628/171318) figured that out!

---

I first thought that you want to print the lines in range in the reverse order, you could pipe to [`tac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) in that case:

```
sed -n '5,10p' file | tac
```

---

If you want to use (GNU) `sed` only, you can use the following script:

```
sed -n '5,10{x;H};${x;s/\n$//p}'
```

If the current line is in the range between `5` and `10` sed will exchange the pattern buffer and the hold buffer using `x`. Now the current line is on top of the hold buffer. After that the pattern buffer (previous hold buffer) will be appended to the hold buffer using `H`. The stores the lines of interest in reverse order in the hold buffer. On end of input `$` we exchange the hold buffer and the pattern buffer, replace the newline at the end and finally print it using `p`. Normal output is disable using the `-n` command line option.

Comment: SO needs a like button... :-)

Comment: The OP isn't asking for reversed lines with `'10,5 p'` - he's just wondering why any line at all would be printed... But anybody who quotes tac gets points in my book.

Comment: @PeterBowers Thanks! Yeah the name of the `tac` command is indeed funny! And the command itself is quite useful.. (However it can be emulated using `sed` ;)

Comment: Wow. that's a pretty neat explanation! I've just started scratching the surface of sed, and Linux in general. I totally got the tac example, but am a little lost with the second. So please forgive my ignorance ;).  I'm guessing the pattern buffer holds the pattern, while the hold buffer holds the match?

Comment: The hold buffer can be seen as a variable, where you can store things. The pattern buffer contains the current line, or the modified current line if you modified it through commands..